# Add fields to User model in Devise New Registration and Edit Registration urls

Tags: ruby, devise

I've been trying to find a solution for a couple days with no luck. Here's the issue, I have created new fields to the user registration process through migration. I have also added these field to attr_accessible. Everything seems in place, but when I visit new_user_registration_url or edit_user_registration_url , only the original fields show. I have made a different project using this technique and I remember running into the same problem and fixing it somehow. I've referenced my previous project, and all models, views, and controllers look identical.

Answer (score 2):

Since devise uses fixed template according to your devise customization. So if you have added some extra fields to your devise table than you need to customize you devise views accordingly(manually)

First you need to generate default devise views

```
rails generate devise:views
```

this will generate views under  views/devise//. Then go ahead and add your attributes manually to views.